# Why do we require convergence of $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\:dx$ for the following integral to tend to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

$\int_{1/n}^{1/m}f(x)\:dx$ $\:\:$ $where \lim_{N \to \infty}\: and\: n>m>N$

The context of this, is that was trying to prove comparison test for convergence of integrals.

Comment: You only need the convergence of the integral on $[0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. If the integral doesn't converge near $0$, you can't conclude: consider $\int_{1/n}^{1/m} \frac{dx}{x^2}=n-m$

Comment: Thanks for the example, can we use convergence of the integral to form an inequality on $\int_{1/n}^{1/m}f(x)\:dx$ to show that it tends to zero explicitly.